# Add overlay image on li

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

Problem: I am trying to make an overlay appear when a list item is hovered upon.

I am new to **html** and I am trying to get a division overlay on a `list item` hover. However the overlay appears in the full width of the screen when I want it only on the `list item` as class `header` which is in gray color. 
I only want the red overlay division to appear on the gray `list item`.

[image: HTML page screenshot]

Here's my code:

```css
.* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.columns {
    float: left;
    width: 33.3%;
    padding: 8px;
}

.price {
    list-style-type: none;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #F9423A;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
}


.price:hover {
    /*box-shadow: 0 8px 12px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2)*/
    background-color: #002A3A;
}


.price:hover .overlay {
    height: 20%;
}

.price .header {
    background-color: #ccd4d7;
    color: #002A3A;
    align-content: center; 
    font-size: 25px;
    height: 100%;
}

.price li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="columns">
<ul class="price">
<li class="header"> li One 
</br>
<img src="../images/closeicon.png" height="50%" width="50%"/> 

<div class="overlay">
<span class="closebutton"> 
<img src="../images/closeicon.png" height="10px" width="10px"/> </span>
<div class="text">li One description
</div>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="columns">
<ul class="price">
<li class="header"> li One 
</br>
<img src="../images/closeicon.png" height="50%" width="50%"/> 

<div class="overlay">
<span class="closebutton"> 
<img src="../images/closeicon.png" height="10px" width="10px"/> </span>
<div class="text">li two description
</div>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="columns">
<ul class="price">
<li class="header"> li three
</br>
<img src="../images/closeicon.png" height="50%" width="50%"/> 

<div class="overlay">
<span class="closebutton"> 
<img src="../images/closeicon.png" height="10px" width="10px"/> </span>
<div class="text">li three description
</div>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Would anybody know how to do this?

Thanks,

Comment: Didn't understood clearly. Is this what you were trying to achieve? ? https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_image_overlay_opacity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `position: relative` to `.price .header`. Adding `position: relative` makes children with `position: absolute` position themselves relative to the parent. Otherwise any element with `position: absolute` positions itself relative to the window object.

Comment: I checked it out again and it works all fine for me - https://youtu.be/uP1_wconUm4